# how to create multiple workbooks that have multiple sheets in each

Tags: r

I have codes to create mutiple excel files. Is it a way to modify it so I can create multiple workbooks at once first and later I can write them into the excel with same name?

My codes are:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)

lst1 <- list(data1 = mpg, data2 = mpg, data3 = mpg, `data4` = mpg)


IDlist <- mpg %>% pull(cyl) %>% unique

make_one_xlsx <- function(this_id){
    lst1 %>% map(~filter(., cyl == this_id)) %>% write_xlsx(paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx"))
}

IDlist %>% map(make_one_xlsx)
```

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary step to "pre-create" empty Excel files. You are not accessing and directly writing data into cells using `write_xlsx()` like you would when coding in VBA. You're reading the Excel information into R memory, make the changes in R, then overwrite the original Excel file with a new one.

Comment: I need to add summary sheet for each excel file. I don't know a way to add it later. That is why I want to have it as workbook first, so I can add pages in and then write excel later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `write_xlsx()` from the `readxl` package, you can pass a list of data frames as the first argument which will create each data frame as its own sheet. The function will also use the name of that list as the Excel display sheet name.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)

# with with some number of data frames
lst1 <- list(data1 = mpg, data2 = mpg, data3 = mpg, `data4` = mpg)

IDlist <- mpg %>% pull(cyl) %>% unique

make_one_xlsx <- function(this_id){
  # make an interim list full of the filtered data
  temp <- lst1 %>% map(~filter(.,cyl == this_id))
  # calculate the summary information and add it to the interim list
  # I have no idea what summary info you need, this is a placeholder
  temp[['Summary']] <- temp %>% map(~summarise_all(.,mean)) %>% bind_rows()
  # write list of data to Excel, the summary table is there now.
  write_xlsx(temp, paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx"))
}

IDlist %>% map(make_one_xlsx)
```

Now you can create Excel files from scratch with all the tabs you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My case is more complicate. I have a list of data.frame, I need to filter them with ID so I can created excel for each ID. Each excel has multiple sheets. used my codes I can created the file I wanted, but I also need to add s summary page to each excel file and I don't know how to after I output excel already. That is why I want to create workbook now, instead of excel. I updated my codes to show you the data and more info.

Comment: If you can get the package installed (requires admin permissions usually) the `xlsx` package has a similar function with more flexibility. That package's `write.xlsx()` has an argument `append=TRUE` which allows you to add a sheet to an existing workbook. Something like `write.xlsx(summaryData, 'existingExcel.xlsx', sheetName='Summary', append=TRUE)`. The `openxlsx` package has similar, but more annoying, functionality if you can't get `xlsx` to install.

Comment: for `make_one_xlsx <- function(this_id){
    lst1 %>% map(~filter(., cyl == this_id)) %>% write_xlsx(paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx"))
}`, where can I add `summary`? can I do`make_one_xlsx <- function(this_id){
    lst1 %>% map(~filter(., cyl == this_id)) %>% write_xlsx(paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx"))%>% write.xlsx(summaryData, paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx")', sheetName='Summary', append=TRUE)`
}

Comment: I am not sure what your `summryData` looks like, but to fit your workflow I'd add code after `lst1 %>% map(~filter(., cyl == this_id)) %>% write_xlsx(paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx"))` which first calculates whatever summary info you want and saves it as `summaryData` and then `write.xlsx(summaryData, paste0("ID_", this_id, ".xlsx")', sheetName='Summary', append=TRUE)`. You could make it much easier by modifying the function to calculate the summary info before the `write.xlsx()`. I updated my previous answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks so much. In fact I want to add legend in the summary page which include hyperlinks to each tabs. Might be too complex to do. Any suggestion? Maybe I could build a data.frame to store the info and add to lst1?

Comment: Not sure you can do that from R since now you're trying to create VBA objects and references. If this is a recurring task or you have many workbooks look into writing a VBA subroutine that will automate that task, if this is a one-off analysis I wouldn't bother and just do it manually. I don't have enough specific information to help you there. Open a new question under VBA for more help with that.